# how to convert comma separated string to comma seperated int in python

Tags: python, casting

i'm trying to convert any timezone time to uk time. i'm getting the value error in the time_format variable.

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

newyork_tz = timezone('America/New_York')
london_tz = timezone('Europe/London')
```

it is in type string and when i'm trying to convert to int it is giving me this error

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2022, 02, 02, 21, 32, 25'

expecting out like below with type int

2022, 02, 02, 21, 28, 15

i'm new to python plz guide me with possible solution

Comment: That's not a string, it's a tuple. A string would have quotes around it.

Comment: Also, your desired output `2022, 02, 02, 21, 28, 15` is not an int. Did you mean a list of ints?

Comment: @Barmar. i've update the code with complete example. plz check

Comment: @j1-lee i'm trying to pass 2022, 02, 02, 21, 28, 15 to time_format variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to parse a datetime. It uses the same format string as `strftime()`.

```
newyork = newyork_tz.localize(datetime.strptime(time_format, format))
```

Comment: thanks it worked for me. i'm getting output as 2022-02-03 02:57:02+00:00. but can I get only the hours and minutes. something like 02:57

Comment: You can format the output however you like, using `newyork.strftime('%H:%M')`.

Comment: thank you very much. I really appreciate you help.